# What is the fundamental group of a modular curve $\mathcal{H}/\Gamma$?

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology

Let $\Gamma$ be a finite index subgroup of $PSL_2(\mathbb{Z})$.

What is the fundamental group of $\mathcal{H}/\Gamma$?

By the Kurosh Subgroup theorem,
$$\Gamma \cong F_n * C_2^{*r} * C_3^{*s}$$
ie, $\Gamma$ is the free product of a free group $F_n$, together with some number of free products of $C_2$ and $C_3$, where $r,s$ are the number of conjugacy classes of torsion elements of order 2 and 3 respectively.

Certainly the fundamental group should be torsion free - could it just be
the quotient of $\Gamma$ by the normal subgroup generated by the torsion elements? (ie, could it just be $F_n$?)

How would I see this?

Comment: Why do you say that the fundamental group should be torsion free? I'm not an expert on modular curves, so maybe I'm missing something, but it seems here that $\mathcal{H}$ is the universal cover of $\mathcal{H}/\Gamma$ (seeing as it's simply connected) and that $\Gamma$ is the group of deck transformations, so $\pi_1(\mathcal{H}/\Gamma)$ is simply $\Gamma$.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi If $\Gamma$ has torsion, then the action of $\Gamma$ on $\mathcal{H}$ has fixed points, above which the quotient map is ramified.

Answer (score 3):

If you treat ${\mathcal H}/\Gamma$ as a topological space, then it is always a connected noncompact surface. Therefore, its fundamental group is indeed free. However, if you treat it as an orbifold, the fundamental group is $\Gamma$.

**Edit.** There is also a more algebraic proof which shows  the following:

**Proposition.** Suppose that $X$ is a finite dimensional contractible CW complex, $G\times X\to X$ is a properly discontinuous cellular action of a group which is a free product of finite groups and cyclic groups. Then for each subgroup $H< G$, $\pi_1(X/H)$ is free.

The proof is a combination of theorems by Armstrong and Kurosh and the fact that each (cyclic) group of prime order fixes a point in $X$.

Comment: The fundamental group of a connected noncompacy surface is always free? Do you have a reference for this?

Comment: @oxeimon: This should be in Hatcher: If $M$ is a noncompact connected PL manifold then it is homotopy equivalent to the (n-1)-dimensional skeleton which is a graph in this case. See also http://mathoverflow.net/questions/18454/fundamental-groups-of-noncompact-surfaces